# Smooks - Multiple templates in a config file

Tags: xml, include, freemarker, smooks

How can I use `#include` to add multiple template files to a smooks config file using freemarker template.

```
 <ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="Response">
  <ftl:template>
  <BODY>
   <C1><#include "template1.ftl"></C1>
   <C2><#include "template2.ftl"></C2>
   ........
  </BODY>       
 </ftl:template>
```

It's not a duplicate question, as here the `#include`s are embedded into another template.

Comment: It's not a duplicate question, as here the `#include`-s are embedded into another template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code of [FreeMarkerTemplateProcessor.java](https://github.com/smooks/smooks/blob/master/smooks-cartridges/templating/src/main/java/org/milyn/templating/freemarker/FreeMarkerTemplateProcessor.java), it seems that you can't use `#include` in an inline template (inline means that the template is directly embedded into the `ftl:template` element), as they don't set the `TemplateLoader` there. But if inside `ftl:template` there's a path instead (like `/com/example/templates/my.ftl`), then the template is loaded from there, and can use `#include` with similar paths (and with relative paths).

Comment: thanks.. that worked!!